# VBA to show result based on combobox value changed

Tags: excel, vba

I my userform look like this:

[image]

I have few criteria which to meet.
1. Different customer will have different process and specification
2. If the ID#(textbox1) is empty, the process and the specification will change as well.
3. Different customer will use different G-chip to carry out their progress.

As below will be my code:

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()ComboBox1.List = Array("Apple", "Banana",   
"Watermelon")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Call CuAl
If TextBox1.Value = "N/A" Then
    Call CustXPTArray
Else
    Call CustWithPTAluArray
End If
End Sub

Sub CustWithPTAlu()
Select Case ComboBox1
    Case "Apple"
        ComboBox2.List = Array("Ni", "NiNi")
    Case "Banana"
        ComboBox2.List = Array("Au", "AuAu")
    Case "Watermelon"
        ComboBox2.List = Array("Pd", "PdPd")
End Select
End Sub

Sub CustWithPTAluArray()
Call CustWithPTAlu
If ComboBox1.Text = "Apple" Then
    TextBox2.Value = IIf(ComboBox2.Value = "Ni", "10S", "20S")
Else
    If ComboBox1.Text = "Banana" Then
        TextBox2.Value = IIf(ComboBox2.Value = "Au", "30S", "40S")
    Else
        TextBox2.Value = IIf(ComboBox2.Value = "Pd", "50S", "60S")
    End If
End If
End Sub

Sub CuAl()
Select Case ComboBox1
    Case "Apple"
        ComboBox3.List = Array("Cu", "Al")
    Case "Banana"
        ComboBox3.List = Array("Cu")
    Case "Watermelon"
        ComboBox3.List = Array("Al")
End Select
End Sub

Sub CustXPT()
ComboBox2.List = Array("Ni", "NiAu", "NiPd", "NiPdAu")
End Sub

Sub CustXPTArray()
Call CustXPT
Select Case ComboBox2
    Case "Ni"
        TextBox2.Value = "70S"
    Case "NiAu"
        TextBox2.Value = "80S"
    Case "NiPd"
        TextBox2.Value = "90S"
    Case "NiPdAu"
        TextBox2.Value = "100S"
End Select
End Sub
```

When I try to run the code, the specification will not change. It will stay with a same number.

I have no idea, how that could happen when I have set all function one by one.

```
Customer: ComboBox1
ID#: TextBox1
G-chip:ComboBox3
Plating Type:ComboBox2
Lower Range:TextBox2
```

Answer (score 0):

All I have done here is put the logic for your form calculations in "calc_form" and then called that whenever a field is changed, in either textbox1/combobox2/combobox3. You may want to think about clearing values from combobox's when criteria changes, mainly to force user to recheck

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
calc_form
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
calc_form
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
calc_form
End Sub

Sub calc_form()
Call CuAl
If TextBox1.Value = "N/A" Then
    Call CustXPTArray
Else
    Call CustWithPTAluArray
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Userform_initialize()
ComboBox1.List = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Watermelon")
End Sub

Sub CustWithPTAlu()
Select Case ComboBox1
    Case "Apple"
        ComboBox2.List = Array("Ni", "NiNi")
    Case "Banana"
        ComboBox2.List = Array("Au", "AuAu")
    Case "Watermelon"
        ComboBox2.List = Array("Pd", "PdPd")
End Select
End Sub

Sub CustWithPTAluArray()
Call CustWithPTAlu
If ComboBox1.Text = "Apple" Then
    TextBox2.Value = IIf(ComboBox2.Value = "Ni", "10S", "20S")
Else
    If ComboBox1.Text = "Banana" Then
        TextBox2.Value = IIf(ComboBox2.Value = "Au", "30S", "40S")
    Else
        TextBox2.Value = IIf(ComboBox2.Value = "Pd", "50S", "60S")
    End If
End If
End Sub

Sub CuAl()
Select Case ComboBox1
    Case "Apple"
        ComboBox3.List = Array("Cu", "Al")
    Case "Banana"
        ComboBox3.List = Array("Cu")
    Case "Watermelon"
        ComboBox3.List = Array("Al")
End Select
End Sub

Sub CustXPT()
ComboBox2.List = Array("Ni", "NiAu", "NiPd", "NiPdAu")
End Sub

Sub CustXPTArray()
Call CustXPT
Select Case ComboBox2
    Case "Ni"
        TextBox2.Value = "70S"
    Case "NiAu"
        TextBox2.Value = "80S"
    Case "NiPd"
        TextBox2.Value = "90S"
    Case "NiPdAu"
        TextBox2.Value = "100S"
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: is that possible that, I add one more function to clear the content when the field change again?

Comment: really you could remove most of them functions and put them under the correct places in the change events - above works so I wouldnt bother changing it now. Anyway on to your question, I wouldnt (and you dont need to) write a new function to clear content. Write the code to clear the other dropdowns under the TextBox1_Change event. You may need to put some code under the combobox events if you want them to clear any values too